# Array of strings getting converted to Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm pushing files to amazon using pre-signed URLs, and modifying the files array with the file name reference inside the `newData` object. (The files array are inside an array of objects called items)

```js
// Add job
const addJob = async(data, user) => {
  const newData = { ...data };

  data.items.map((item, itemIndex) => {
    if (item.files !== []) {
      item.files.map(async(file, fileIndex) => {
        const uploadConfig = await axios.get(`/api/s3upload`, {
          params: {
            name: file.name,
          },
        });

        console.log(uploadConfig.data.key);

        newData.items[itemIndex].files[fileIndex] = uploadConfig.data.key;
        await axios.put(uploadConfig.data.url, file);
      });
    }
  });

  console.log(newData);

  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/jobs', newData);
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_JOB,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

The file references comes in the `uploadConfig.data.key` and are being save into the `newData` object.

When this function is executed, something peculiar happens:

- the console log of `newData` returns the correct array of references to the files
- the files are uploaded just fine
- the request made to /api/jobs, which is passing newData, sends an array of objects that contains { path: ... }

`console.log(newData):`

[image]

Post request:

[image]

Comment: Hello, Items is still an array of objects. What's happening here is it is storing the value as an object in the array because multiple items are getting returned.

Comment: Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(newData, null, 2))`; that will get you the value of `newData` at the time of logging.

Comment: Please don't use `.map()` for simple iteration. Use `.forEach()` or an actual loop.

Comment: @HereticMoney, did that, it did returned the `      "files": [
        {
          "path": "2564AA38-83AD-42BE-9AF6-0CA08E929026.jpeg"
        }
      ],`

Comment: Well, what's happening is that the post to /api/jobs is happening before the map loops, what would be a good approach to avoid that?

Comment: Using `await Promise.all(data.items.map(async (item, itemIndex)) => {` will do the trick.

Comment: Please provide data as text, not as a picture of text.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does this because `forEach` and `map` are not promise-aware. It cannot support async and await. You cannot use `await` in `forEach` or `map`.

`for` loops are promise-aware, thus replacing the loops with `for` loops and marking them as `await` returns the expected behaviour.

source: [zellwk article](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/)

Corrected (functioning) code:

```js
  const addJob = async (data, user) => {
    const newData = { ...data };
    const { items } = data;

    const loop = async () => {
      for (let outer in items) {
        if (items[outer].files !== []) {
          const loop2 = async () => {
            for (let inner in items[outer].files) {
              const uploadConfig = await axios.get(`/api/s3upload`, {
                params: {
                  name: items[outer].files[inner].name,
                },
              });
              const res = await axios.put(uploadConfig.data.url, items[outer].files[inner])
              newData.items[outer].files[inner] = uploadConfig.data.key;
            }
          };

          await loop2();
        }
      }
    };

    await loop();
    try {
      const res = await axios.post('/api/jobs', newData);
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_JOB,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```